# Using IF and ISBLANK statement to determine a range of cells if any of them have information in them

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a formula where I am checking for a range of cells whether or not they are blank.

If all of them are blank I want to return another blank.

If any of the cells in the range are not blank, I want to return a value `Major Milestone Due`.

Here is the formula I currently have:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(BM2:BQ2),"","Major Milestone Due")
```

It is returning everything as `Major Milestone Due`, even if there are certain row ranges with all blank cells.

Answer (score 19):

`COUNTA` will give the number of cells in a range that are **not empty**.

So try ...

```
 =IF(NOT(COUNTA(BM2:BQ2)),"","Major Milestone Due")
```

Comment: The basic formula:

   NOT(COUNTA(BM2:BQ2))

is applicable with more logical operator, such as:

    AND(COUNTA(BN2),NOT(COUNTA(BM2:BQ2)))

Answer (score 9):

#### Your formula is correct if it is entered as an **array formula**.

The `isblank` doesn't work for an array unless you enter it as an array formula by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>. It will look like this by having curly brackets around it:

`{=IF(ISBLANK(BM2:BQ2),"","Major Milestone Due")}`

Also, an if - counta will do this no problem as well -

`=IF(COUNTA(BM2:BQ2)=0,"","Major Milestone Due")`

Comment: The array formula isn't quite correct. This version will only go from `TRUE` to `FALSE` if the first cell in the range contains a value. In order to correctly check all cells in the range, `AND` needs to be added -- `{=IF(AND(ISBLANK(BM2:BQ2)),"","Major Milestone Due")}`

Comment: @MarcusHughes why would that be? It's an *array formula* and works on the entire array

Comment: I don't know the *why* of it exactly, but I tested it (Excel 2010) and it doesn't work with just `ISBLANK`. Try entering that formula, keep the first cell in the range blank, then enter data in a later cell in the range.... The `ISBLANK` condition will still return `TRUE`. Only if you enter data into the first cell will it return `FALSE` correctly. Now try adding `AND`. If any cell in the range gets data added to it, it will return `FALSE` as it should. (I'm assuming this isn't just some weird fluke with 2010.)

Answer (score 5):

An important thing to consider is your definition of "blank". Based on the fact that you used the wording "I want to return another blank", it would appear that you're defining "blank" as cells that *appear* blank, but which may actually contain a formula that outputs `""` and therefore aren't **empty**.

The `COUNTA` and `ISBLANK` methods won't work if you want to handle these sorts of cells as blanks, since those two formulas look for truly *empty* cells. To handle formulas which output `""`, you have two options:

- If you always know the size of your range, you can use either of the following:
  `=IF( COUNTBLANK(BM2:BQ2)=5, "", "Major Milestone Due")`
  `=IF( COUNTIF(BM2:BQ2,"")=5, "", "Major Milestone Due")`
  where **5** is the size of your range. This method does not work as well with dynamic ranges.

- A slightly more complex formula (at least, more complex to explain!) uses `SUMPRODUCT`:
  `=IF( SUMPRODUCT(--(BM2:BQ2<>""))=0, "", "Major Milestone Due")`

(Note that `COUNTIF(BM2:BQ2,"<>")` has the same issue as `COUNTA`.)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the ISBLANK in an OR or AND function to aggregate the conditions.

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score -1):

I arrived at this page in search of the answer to an almost identical question.

When I saw that `COUNTA` was mentioned, I knew almost immediately what to do. In a slightly different context, I have a range of columns to the left of a column that I want to say `not started` if all cells in the same row are empty (blank).

The following formula works for me.

```
=IF(COUNTA(P3:U3)=0,"Not Started"...)
```

The ellipsis indicate that there are several additional `IF` functions in my formula, which performs further tests on the range if one or more is populated.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Noticed your answer attracted a downvote.  The likely reason is that we try to avoid duplication.  Each answer is intended to provide a solution that is substantially different from what has already been contributed.  This essentially duplicates the second part of Raystafarian's answer.

Comment: My answer should have been cast as a comment.