# Format entire row in Excel Table if row is empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have a Table (as opposed to a Range) defined in Excel 2010, named `Table1`.

The table has blank rows separating groups of 3 to 5 rows with data. Note that not every column in every "non-blank" row contains data. However data exists in column B (named `Table1[IdMap]`) for every non-blank row.

I want to format the table (either using Conditional Formatting or static formatting) such that all of the all-blank rows have an off-white background color.

So far I've tried the following Conditional Formatting rules with no luck:

1. Select `Table1` (using <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> while the cell-marquee is in the table)
2. Conditional Formatting > Rules > New Rule > Use a formula...
3. "Format values where this formula is true":

   - `=ISBLANK( $B:$B )`
   - `=ISBLANK( INDIRECT("Table1[IdMap]"))`
   - `=ISBLANK( INDIRECT("RC[-2]",0) )`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer also on superuser: [Using IF and ISBLANK statement to determine a range of cells if any of them have information in them](https://superuser.com/questions/722504/using-if-and-isblank-statement-to-determine-a-range-of-cells-if-any-of-them-have).

Just use in conditional formatting =NOT(COUNTA($B:$B))

Comment: You actually don't need the `IF`, just `=NOT(COUNTA($B:$B))` as you're just saying IF true, then true, else false. :)

Comment: I'll edit the answer :).

Answer (score 0):

This formula worked for me: `=ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2)))`

1. `ROW()` finds the current row number
2. `ADDRESS()` returns the absolute address as text, in this case the current row, second column
3. `INDIRECT()` converts the text given into a cell reference
4. `ISBLANK()` checks if the cell is blank

So this formula will return TRUE for every cell in a row where column B is blank.

**Steps**

1. Select your table range (using <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> while the cell-marquee is in the table)
2. *Conditional Formatting* > *New Rule*
3. Select Use a formula to determine which cells to format
4. Under 'Format values where this formula is true:'

   - Enter `=ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2)))`
5. Click *Format* to format your rule
6. Click *Ok* and you're done!